# помогите!!!Не могу понять в чем проблема

Tags: pascal

Не могу разобраться в чем проблема,вроде все end и begin на месте,но все-равно выдает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код нужно всегда выкладывать текстом, а не картинкой (копировать и вставлять). Так люди смогут его скопировать.

Comment: `than`?  Такого нет, есть только `then`, а у вас как-раз после первого `end` и стоит этот `than`. Заменить на `then`.

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, поставьте галочку слева от ответа ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Перед `else` не ставится точка с запятой.

Замените все `ReadLn` кроме первого на `WriteLn`.

*И помещайте код в вопрос текстом, а не картинкой.*