# Какая-то проблема с отрицательными числами, или просто выдает 0, или если несколько, то выдает одно из них и 0

Tags: c, массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{

  int i,k;
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
  printf("Введите размер массива: ");
  scanf("%d", &k);  
    
    int A[100];
    int m=0;
    int B[100];


    printf("Введите элементы массива\n");
        
  for (i = 0; i<k; i++)
  {
    printf("mas[%i] = ", i);
    scanf("%d", &A[i]);

            if(A[i]<0)
        {
            m++;
            B[m]=A[i];
        }
    }


    if (m>0)
    {
        for(i=0; i<m; i++)
        {
            printf("Отрицательные числа: %d", B[i]);
        }
    }

    else 
    printf("В массиве A нет отрицательных элементов ");
    
}
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1103139

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (A[i] < 0)
    {
        //m++;
        B[m++] = A[i];
    }
```